# trying to rotate a triangle with complex numbers in tkinter python

Tags: python, rotation, tkinter, complex-numbers

the first method is mine, the other two are from here
http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-complex-canvas.htm

so i call the rotate method that calls the second one that calls the first one. the first one gets the xy coordinates from the angle that is passed, and then work with them to translate the triangle.

self.x and self.y are the coordinates on the canvas of the triangle, the middle of the lower line of the triangle

i guess there's another way to do this, much simpler.

and i have found this btw, but it doesn't really help

[How do I rotate a polygon in python on a Tkinter Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408779/how-do-i-rotate-a-polygon-in-python-on-a-tkinter-canvas)

Comment: it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: i want you to try and find the bug in this code with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post implied difficulty with understanding how to rotate triangles using complex numbers. 
After reading your comment in reply to my answer I have edited my code sample to demonstrate a way to get the angle from keyboard input.
I have no experience with Tkinter so perhaps someone can help with a more state of the art approach.
Gleaned from [Tkinter: Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and [The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#entry.Entry.config-method)

When you enter the keypress event handler, the Entry widget's text, retrieved with text.get(), doesn't include the latest keypress character.

The angle entered is in degrees and can be negative.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog as tks

import cmath,math

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root,width=200, height=200)
c.pack()

# keypress event
def key(event):
    text.focus_force()
    ch=event.char

    # handle backspace
    if ch=='\x08':
        if len(text.get())>1 :
            entry_text=text.get()[:-1]
            if entry_text=='-': entry_text='0'
        else:
            entry_text='0'
    else:
        entry_text=text.get()+ch 

    # we want an integer
    try:
        angle_degrees=int(entry_text)
        cangle = cmath.exp(angle_degrees*1j*math.pi/180)


        offset = complex(center[0], center[1])
        newxy = []
        for x, y in triangle:
            v = cangle * (complex(x, y) - offset) + offset
            newxy.append(v.real)
            newxy.append(v.imag)
        c.coords(polygon_item, *newxy)
    except ValueError:
        print "not integer"

text = Entry(root)
text.bind("<Key>", key)

text.pack()
text.focus_force()

# a triangle
triangle = [(50, 50), (150, 50), (150, 150)]

polygon_item = c.create_polygon(triangle)
center = 100, 100


mainloop()
```

Comment: that's where i found the code (and edited it). i need the rotation with the angle given from the user, not rotation with the mouse

Answer (score 0):

roitation of anything is best done by expressing every point (x,y) as a complex number x + iy Then Rotate each point by multiplying by the comples number  cos(angle) + i sin(angle)